# How to get Bluetooth LE Services in different activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm now working on Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) device,

I can now connect with my device by my android app,

And also can get the service/characteristics from my device,

Now, I hope that all activity can use the BLE connection to write something into device,

How should I set my BluetoothGattCallback?

i really have no ideal,

is there any sample that I may reference for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The developer documentation has a great example of putting your Blueooth LE functionality in a Service that can be accessed by all Activities in your app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: Hi gyoda, I've write the BluetoothGattCallback function on my first activity, and how the second activity get information by "onCharacteristicChanged()" in BluetoothGattCallback function?

Comment: You should implement all Bluetooth communication and callbacks in a Service, and then broadcast Intents to notify any listeners of new information available.